# Accidently deleted C:\Users\public

Tags: windows-7

I recently deleted my public folder on accident `C:\Users\public`. I have tried restoring it, recovery, creating a new User account, undelete. I tried some registry fixes found online, tried `sfc /scannow` but nothing has helped. I am unable to install some applications like Skype. when I try it tells me it can't access `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`. I can't edit most files, and whenever I create a new folder and name it, i get a message that says:

> Could not find this item

if I hit try again it works. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I suggest using a restoration point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accidentally deleted user profiles on Windows 7 - can't log on with other users now](http://superuser.com/questions/219082/accidentally-deleted-user-profiles-on-windows-7-cant-log-on-with-other-users)

Comment: I do not have a restore point that will work.

Comment: [This](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/69334-public-folders-restore.html) worked for me.  Just tested it.

Comment: I've already attempted this fix and it doesn't work for me. The issue is that THE Public folder has been deleted, not just an ordinary pubic folder.  Step 10: Open the C:\Users\Public folder.

Comment: This folder doesn't exist. While I can create a folder with that name and all the other folders it contains, they are not recognized as they should be. The following error is returned when attempting to access - Item Not Found. Could not find this item. This is no longer located in C:\Users. Verify the item's location and try again.